# Test using StepVerifier blocks when using Spring WebClient with retry

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webclient

**EDIT:** here https://github.com/wujek-srujek/reactor-retry-test is a repository with all the code.

I have the following Spring `WebClient` code to POST to a remote server (Kotlin code without imports for brevity):

```
private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

@Component
class Client(private val webClient: WebClient) {

    companion object {
        const val maxRetries = 2L
        val firstBackOff = Duration.ofSeconds(5L)
        val maxBackOff = Duration.ofSeconds(20L)
    }

    fun send(uri: URI, data: Data): Mono<Void> {
        return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(uri)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(data)
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .doOnSubscribe {
                logger.info { "Calling backend, uri: $uri" }
            }
            .retryExponentialBackoff(maxRetries, firstBackOff, maxBackOff, jitter = false) {
                logger.debug { "Call to $uri failed, will retry (#${it.iteration()} of max $maxRetries)" }
            }
            .doOnError {
                logger.error { "Call to $uri with $maxRetries retries failed with $it" }
            }
            .doOnSuccess {
                logger.info { "Call to $uri succeeded" }
            }
            .then()
    }
}
```

(It returns an empty `Mono` as we don't expect an answer, nor do we care about it.)

I would like to test 2 cases, and one of them is giving me headaches, namely the one in which I want to test that all the retries have been fired. We are using `MockWebServer` (https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) and the `StepVerifier` from reactor-test.  (The test for success is easy and doesn't need any virtual time scheduler magic, and works just fine.) Here is the code for the failing one:

```
@JsonTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Client::class, ClientConfiguration::class])
class ClientITest @Autowired constructor(
    private val client: Client
) {
    lateinit var server: MockWebServer

    @BeforeEach
    fun `init mock server`() {
        server = MockWebServer()
        server.start()
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun `shutdown server`() {
        server.shutdown()
    }

   @Test
   fun `server call is retried and eventually fails`() {
       val data = Data()
       val uri = server.url("/server").uri()
       val responseStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

       repeat((0..Client.maxRetries).count()) {
           server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(responseStatus.value()))
       }

       StepVerifier.withVirtualTime { client.send(uri, data) }
           .expectSubscription()
           .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10)) // wait for the first retry
           .expectNextCount(0)
           .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(20)) // wait for the second retry
           .expectNextCount(0)
           .expectErrorMatches {
               val cause = it.cause
               it is RetryExhaustedException &&
                       cause is WebClientResponseException &&
                       cause.statusCode == responseStatus
           }
           .verify()

       // assertions
       }
   }
```

I am using `withVirtualTime` because I don't want the test to take nearly seconds.
The problem is that the test blocks indefinitely. Here is the (simplified) log output:

```
okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer      : MockWebServer[51058] starting to accept connections
Calling backend, uri: http://localhost:51058/server
MockWebServer[51058] received request: POST /server HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Call to http://localhost:51058/server failed, will retry (#1 of max 2)
Calling backend, uri: http://localhost:51058/server
MockWebServer[51058] received request: POST /server HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Call to http://localhost:51058/server failed, will retry (#2 of max 2)
```

As you can see, the first retry works, but the second one blocks. I don't know how to write the test so that it doesn't happen. To make matters worse, the client will actually use jitter, which will make the timing hard to anticipate.

The following test using `StepVerifier` but without `WebClient` works fine, even with more retries:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime {
        Mono
            .error<RuntimeException>(RuntimeException())
            .retryExponentialBackoff(5,
                                     Duration.ofSeconds(5),
                                     Duration.ofMinutes(2),
                                     jitter = true) {
                println("Retrying")
            }
            .then()
    }
        .expectSubscription()
        .thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(1)) // doesn't matter
        .expectNextCount(0)
        .expectError()
        .verify()
}
```

Could anybody help me fix the test, and ideally, explain what is wrong?

Comment: how does it behave if you do a single large `thenAwait` like in the second example?

Comment: also, is the `retryExponentialBackoff` an custom extension method? the core operator is called `retryBackoff`...

Comment: @SimonBaslé - it blocks the same. The `retryExponentialBackoff` function comes from here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kotlin-extensions/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/reactor/kotlin/extra/retry/RetryExtensions.kt, written by ... you?

Comment: haha was so focused on core operator that I forgot about extra extensions... can you try with the vanilla core `retryBackoff` operator (in core since 3.2), see if that is "only" a bug in reactor-extra?

Comment: I will do it when I get to my computer, will take a couple hours.

Comment: @SimonBaslé The test also blocks when I use the core operator. If you want me to, I can create a Github repo with the code so that it is easy to test.

Comment: The reason I originally chose the extension was that I couldn't find a way to execute an action (like to log) whenever a retry happens. The custom operator (and the extension, in a nice Kotlin lambda) allows this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of virtual time and the way the clock is manipulated in `StepVerifier`. The `thenAwait` methods are not synchronized with the underlying scheduling (that happens for example as part of the `retryBackoff` operation). This means that the operator submits retry tasks at a point where the clock has already been advanced by one day. So the second retry is scheduled for `+ 1 day and 10 seconds`, since the clock is at `+1 day`. After that, the clock is never advanced so the additional request is never made to `MockWebServer`.

Your case is made even more complicated in the sense that there is an additional component involved, the `MockWebServer`, that still works "in real time".
Though advancing the virtual clock is a very quick operation, the response from the `MockWebServer` still goes through a socket and thus has some amount of latency to the retry scheduling, which makes things more complicated from the test writing perspective.

One possible solution to explore would be to externalize the creation of the `VirtualTimeScheduler` and tie `advanceTimeBy` calls to the `mockServer.takeRequest()`, in a parallel thread.

Comment: I have a similar problem when trying to test that stream that needs to continue after `retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(...))` is really continuing. without the virtual timer, test will take a very long time. Can you a little bit elaborate on how can advance the timer for `retry` ?